# Query fails to execute but returns no error - Python

Tags: python, mysql

My query returns no error but doesn't commit to my database.

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import date

def ImportKey():
    testsite_array = []
    converted_list = []

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='USER', password='PASSWORD', host='HOST', database='DATABASE')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    keyType = input("Valid types: Day, Month, Life:\n > ")

    if keyType == "Day":
        with open('Keys.txt') as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                testsite_array.append(line)
        
        for element in testsite_array:
            converted_list.append(element.strip())
        
        sql_query = "INSERT INTO `DailyK`(`keyDaily`) VALUES (%s)"
        
        cursor.execute(sql_query, (converted_list[0], ))
        cnx.commit()
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
```

Why does this code not work? It returns no error and from what I can see there is nothing wrong with it. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutly sure the query is executed ? Have you put a `print` after the `sql_query` to ensure you go there ? And print the converted_list[0]

Comment: Well how can I execute a whole array of values instead of just value 0. It indeed holds a value but it just doesnt execute and commit it to the database.